# Archlinux Chroot Won't run error input/output error

Tags: linux, chroot

I'm new in Archlinux. I faced this problem I think there is problem with glibc library.

When I run that command `arch-chroot /mnt`:

```
chroot: failed to run command /bin/bash : input/output error
```

And also that command `chroot /mnt`:

```
chroot: failed to run command usr/bin/zsh: input/output error
```

I have another problem , when I boot to my archlinux system that's why I want to run `chroot`.

This message appear:

```
"mount : /new_root : unkown filesystem type "ext4" dmesg may have more information after failed mount system call . Error : Failed to mount "UUID= *** " on real root"
```

**[Solved]**
I had problem with glibc library and this execute and install packages
and Have some errors from my hard drive I make sure it's work but have problems with my system file
Chroot can't go into
even Pacstrap has problem with exec : input/output error the package won't install as I mention before glibc library
after I format my drive
It's working and I install Archlinux
Thanks everyone for help !

Comment: Have you tried to verify if your partition is not mounted read only by examining `mount`? have you tried to reboot?

Comment: Yes , I have tried it
/dev/sda3 on /mnt type ext4 (rw,relatime)
and I have another problem when I boot to my archlinux system that's why I want to run chroot , this message appear 
"mount : /new_root : unkown filesystem type "ext4"
dmesg may have more information after failed mount system call .
Error : Failed to mount "UUID= *** " on real root"

Comment: Add this in your original post by editing it. You should try to run: `e2fsck -y /dev/XXX`. Is it a hard drive, SSD?

Comment: it's hard drive

Comment: the output 
e2fsck 1.47.0 
/dev/sda3 is mounted 
e2fsck : cannot continue , aborting 
when I umount my drive and run command 
/dev/sda3 : clean , 609306/2621440 files , 7691709/10485760 blocks

Comment: Please edit your question so it contains an actual question and add more details on what are you trying to do, such as where are you running **arch-chroot** from, the output of `ls -l /mnt/bin/bash` and such.